# One word that can be used to represent Weak student?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

Is there a word/term in English that describes a student that has bad grades, weak performance...

I am writing a PhD thesis so I need a word that can be understood by native and non-native English speakers.

Example:

> The heuristic model gives to better students an opportunity to find possible solutions, whereas **weaker students** are encouraged to locate at least one, from many, to the problem.

Comment: I've met a number of people who would describe the process of completing their PhD as writhing ;-)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Thanks for pointing out the typos. PS: I am not writing a thesis on strong vs. weak students :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate terms for "weak student" are "[underachiever](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Underachiever)" [(consider this Ngram)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=underachievers%2Cnonachievers%2Cunderperformers%2Clow+achievers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunderachievers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnonachievers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunderperformers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clow%20achievers%3B%2Cc0), and "[underachieving](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weak+students%2Cunderachieving+students%2Cnonachieving+students%2Cunderperforming+students%2Clow+achieving+students&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweak%20students%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunderachieving%20students%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnonachieving%20students%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunderperforming%20students%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clow%20achieving%20students%3B%2Cc0)/low achieving student."

For your example, consider "lower achieving students."

> The heuristic model gives **higher achieving students** an opportunity to find possible solutions, whereas **lower achieving ones** are ...

Consider also "[lower performing students](http://www.gse.harvard.edu/cepr-resources/files/news-events/sdp-spi-placement-memo.pdf)," "[low scoring students](http://p.washingtontimes.com/news/2014/feb/5/school-party-high-scoring-students-condemned-caste/)," and "[low graded students](http://www.democraticunderground.com/discuss/duboard.php?az=view_all&address=104x5412342)":

> The heuristic model gives **higher performing students** an opportunity to find possible solutions, whereas **lower performing ones** are ...
>
> The heuristic model gives **higher scoring students** an opportunity to find possible solutions, whereas **lower scoring ones** are ...
>
> The heuristic model gives **higher graded students** an opportunity to find possible solutions, whereas **lower graded ones** are ...

Comment: I've modified the example sentence. You might want to edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for letting me know, Mari-Lou. But what still makes me cringe in the example is "gives "to" better students an opportunity..." I'm pretty sure the phrase could work just as well, not to say better, without that redundant "to." https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gives+students+an%2Cgives+to+students+an&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgives%20students%20an%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

The term struggling learner, or [struggling student](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22struggling%20students%22), is often used to describe a student who has difficulty in keeping pace with their classmates or expected learning benchmarks in a developmentally appropriate environment. They are separate from students who may have [special needs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_needs) or who have been identified as [at-risk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-risk_students).

Comment: I think struggling is really good and the others aren't but still +1.

Answer (score 2):

**[nonachiever](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nonachiever)** (or non-achiever)

> a student who fares poorly in the classroom or has failing grades.

---

Other than that, **"weak student"** is correct also and more common.

> [weak:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weak) Lacking aptitude or skill: *a weak student; weak in math.*

Answer (score 2):

***[Dunce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dunce)***, but probably not in this context ;)

Answer (score 0):

"Slow learner". A term for those students who simply take more time than others to learn something.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing references for your suggestion?

Comment: Here is a reference where it is mentioned that a "slow learner" is the one who learns at a pace slower than their peers: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://schooledn.py.gov.in/ssarmsa/pdf/SlowLearnersGuidelines.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwilt_iJrLL7AhXMUGwGHR53ApUQFnoECBUQBg&usg=AOvVaw3sD3Z1MI_ioHLoEGQLtVv-